# Flutter Bloc Equatable state with one mutual property across all states classes

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to figure out the best way to define my Search Bloc's State to preserve `text` property (search key) across all state classes.

Currently, it looks like this:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:project/models/searchResults.dart';

class SearchState extends Equatable {
  SearchState([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class SearchStateEmpty extends SearchState {
  final String text;
  SearchStateEmpty({this.text});
  @override
  String toString() => 'SearchStateEmpty';
}

class SearchStateLoading extends SearchState {
  final String text;
  SearchStateLoading({this.text});
  @override
  String toString() => 'SearchStateLoading';
}

class SearchStateSuccess extends SearchState {
  final String text;
  final List<RestaurantSearchItem> items;

  SearchStateSuccess({this.text, this.items}) : super([text, items]);

  @override
  String toString() => 'SearchStateSuccess { items: ${items.length} }';
}

class SearchStateError extends SearchState {
  final String text;
  final String error;

  SearchStateError({this.text, this.error}) : super([text, error]);

  @override
  String toString() => 'SearchStateError';
}
```

Is there a better way of using `text` property than defining it throughout all state classes?

This would not be as bad as it is now if I wouldn't have to use `currentState` property every time an event does not have it. For example:

```
SearchStateEmpty(text: currentState.text);
...
SearchStateLoading(text: event.text);
...
SearchStateSuccess(text: currentState.text, items: results.items);
```

I was looking for examples in Flutter docs but all I was able to find out was that I should either use different blocs for it or ditch `equatable` (which I want to keep since it's pretty nice to have).

Any suggestions with examples would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I was doing it was sort of antipattern. With some help, I was able to find a more clean way to use the current state in my state classes.

Code now looks like this:

```
class SearchState extends Equatable {
  final String text;
  SearchState(this.text,
      [List<RestaurantSearchItem> items = const [], String error = ''])
      : super([text, items, error]);
}

class SearchStateEmpty extends SearchState {
  SearchStateEmpty({String text})
      : super(text); // Here I want to use text from SearchState

  SearchStateEmpty.fromState(SearchState state) : super(state.text);

  @override
  String toString() => 'SearchStateEmpty';
}

class SearchStateLoading extends SearchState {
  final String text;

  SearchStateLoading({this.text})
      : super(text); // Here I  want to set text that comes from event

  @override
  String toString() => 'SearchStateLoading';
}

class SearchStateError extends SearchState {
  final String error;

  SearchStateError({this.error, String text}) : super(text, [], error);
  // Text comes from SearchState, error comes from event

  SearchStateError.fromState(SearchState state, {this.error})
      : super(state.text, [], error);

  @override
  String toString() => 'SearchStateError';
}

class SearchStateSuccess extends SearchState {
  final List<RestaurantSearchItem> items;

  SearchStateSuccess({this.items, String text}) : super(text, items, null);

  SearchStateSuccess.fromState(SearchState state, {this.items})
      : super(state.text, items, null);

  @override
  String toString() => 'SearchStateSuccess { items: ${items.length} }';
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what's the entry point for your state? I sort of have the same use case, but the property I need comes from a different bloc, which I'm subscribed to, but not sure how to instantiate it after the initial state call?

Comment: this is not the best pattern. However, you can use it in a case when you need to share the same property among different states without the need to set it every time you change the state.